# How can i save automatically the SSH_CLIENT at login?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

i want to save the user's IP when he connects to it's home folder, this is because i'm a user in a server where my team has a folder where our public_html is located, but we use the same account, so i just want to register who connected.

So i want to make a script that triggers when a connection is made and save the user's IP into a hidden file.

But i don't know if i could leave running a script in background to do it, and How?

Comment: Connects over what protocol?

Comment: protocol ssh and port 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a root on that machine, you can simply check the auth log / messages / journal / ... (depends on the distribution). By default sshd logs all you need already.

If you're not a root, then you'll have to keep in mind this will never be secure. You can do this in the user's bash profile, but:

1. Since it's running as the same user, whoever logs in can just change the file (you can't hide it)
2. Anyone can workaround the script by executing some other command instead of the shell (for example `ssh user@host /some/command` will not be logged)
3. It's not secret.

If that's ok with you, then you just need to add this to bashrc

```
echo "new connection at $(date) from ${SSH_CLIENT}" >> ~/your_connection_log
```

Comment: @omitsu-dæmon : Are you the root by the way? ;)

Comment: Thanks, i'm not root. And yes, it's not secure, but if someone erases the file or modify something i'll notice it and that's enough for me (it's a small team)

Comment: "modify something i'll notice it" -> no you won't :) Not trying to argue, just making sure you understand what this solution cannot provide.

Comment: See the other answer too - it should be way better actually.

Answer (score 0):

Different solution, which should've been the default actually. Most distributions provide login history which you can request for your account without root privileges.

Running `last your_username` should give you the details of last few logins which cannot be manipulated by the user. (the log can possibly be spammed with entries however)